# sharding using jpa repository dynamically

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, sharding, spring-repositories

I have 3 shards(3 different Ips, usernames and passwords). I am using spring boot, spring jpa to save the data in DB. Let's say Customer is my entity. Let's assume, based on some organizationId, I need to insert/update/select the data from different databases.
Current approach :

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long customerId;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private Long organizationId;

}

package lane1;
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepo1 extends CrudRepository<Customer,Long> {
}

package lane2;
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepo2 extends CrudRepository<Customer,Long> {
}

package lane3;
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepo3 extends CrudRepository<Customer,Long> {
}

I am creating 3 datasources(DatasourceLane1, DatasourceLane2, DatasourceLane3) and setting the base packages in the configuration class.

@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("DatasourceLane1")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "lane1", entityManagerFactoryRef = "lane1EntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "lane1TransactionManager")
public class DBConfigurationLane1 {

    @NotNull
    private String username;

    @NotNull
    private String password;

    @NotNull
    private String url;

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    //@Primary
    @Bean
    DataSource dataSourceLane1() throws SQLException {
        HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource();
        dataSource.setUsername(username);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        dataSource.setJdbcUrl(url);
        return dataSource;
    }



    //@Primary
    @Bean(name = "lane1EntityManagerFactory")
    public EntityManagerFactory propEntityManagerFactory() throws SQLException {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
//        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setPersistenceUnitName("lane1");
        em.setDataSource(dataSourceLane1());
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        em.setPackagesToScan("lane1");
        em.setJpaProperties(properties);
        em.afterPropertiesSet();
        return em.getObject();
    }

    //@Primary
    @Bean(name = "lane1TransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager propTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("lane1EntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory barEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(barEntityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

Similarly I have datasource2 and datasource3.

```
My goal is to have single repository class and dynamically use different datasource based on organizationId. 

NOTE : I want to reuse all SimpleJpaRepository(CrudRepository) methods too.


It would be great if someone helps me with code examples. Thank you in advance.
```

Comment: I believe what you are trying to do is an antipattern, difficult to test.

Comment: May I know why is it an antipattern. According to me, I'm trying to loosely couple a repository and a data source.

Comment: According to the documentation I didn't find any possibility to switch the datasource for defined @Repository. Even if it would be possible in some non standard way this 'dynamic switch' I see as an antipattern. This that you want to save a customer to different database based on organisation Id is ok for me if it is your requirement, but it sounds more like a 'low' business logic. I would define a service in which you can make a dispatch. you can also test such a dispatcher nicely in unit test without any spring context. and your code in other places can use this 'proxy' dispatcher.